# MATLAB correlation between 2 variables of different sizes

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have two variables both class double
X = 11x3 Matrix (Showing number of Negative, Neutral, Positive elements in each row)

Y = 11x1 (showing prices)

How would I show the correlation between these two variables and also fit this to a Linear regression model.

I have tried :

> > corrcoef([X,Y])

ans =

```
1.0000    0.3119    0.6753    0.0996
0.3119    1.0000    0.4582   -0.0565
0.6753    0.4582    1.0000   -0.0627
0.0996   -0.0565   -0.0627    1.0000
```

But not sure if this is correct

Many thanks

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific problem with your code is that in your line `corrcoef([X,Y])` you just lumped your `X` and `Y` into one variable.  You can definitely get the answer that you want out of this matrix (the off-diagonal terms are the correlation between the columns of X and your Y) but this might not be quite what you were expecting.

When you are unsure, I always recommend breaking the problem down into the smallest steps.  In this case, things are perhaps confusing for you because your `X` has three columns while your `Y` only has one column.  What does `corrcoef` do in this case?  If you're not sure, I'd suggest breaking it down into smaller steps...

For the operation that you are interested in (correlation with `Y` and a linear regression), there is no interdependence between the three columns of `X`.  So, a good simplifying step would be to deal with the 3 columns independently.  You can do it in a `for` loop (yes, you can do it all vectorized at once, but doing it in a `for` loop makes it easier to understand when one is unsure)...

```
%see the correation between the two variables
for I=1:3
   x_foo = X(:,I)

   %http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html
   c = corrcoeff(x_foo,Y)
end
```

Then, you can do the next step...the linear regression.  Use the polyfit function to fit a line.

```
figure;
for I=1:3
   x_foo = X(:,I);

   %http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html
   N = 1;  % order of the desired polynominal.  N=1 means a line
   p = polyfit(x_foo,Y,N);  %N=1 will fit a line

   %plot
   subplot(3,1,I)
   plot(x_foo,Y,'o',x_foo,polyval(p,x_foo),'s');
   legend('Data','Linear Fit');
end
```

Comment: Great, I really appreciate the help. but how would i assess the goodness of each model?

Comment: The correlation value is a measure of goodness of a linear fit model.  More explicitly, you can do `[p,S] = polyfit(x_foo,Y,N);` and get the goodness of fit from the `S` output...see the link that I provided to the Matlab `polyfit` help page for an explanation of the terms in the `S` output.

Comment: What I have done is created a unique histogram for each day of tweets that either shows one of the 3 types of sentiment categories and trying to find how this distribution correlates to the price change of a commodity. For each day i have have found the number of positive negative and neutral tweets and now I must fit a regression model and use the goodness of the fit as a metric to determine the correlation.

Comment: Have you tried the code and looked at the output?  "Goodness of Fit" is not a universal statement...by looking at how the model does and does not fit your data, you can decide what error quantification is most appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Yh I had a go. What im trying to do is build a model using 3 descriptive variables and 1 subject and determine how well it fits the data

Comment: The above code does gives you the models.  You need to define what "goodness of fit" is relevant to you.  For example, RMS error between the model and your data would be:  `sqrt(mean((Y - polyval(p,x_foo)).^2))`